# Python Web crawler encoutered mysterious javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler

I was trying to crawl a web page("https://www.kuaishou.com/photo/403873037/3976861374") with requests.

My requests headers are

```
{
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64, x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
        }
```

Sometimes I got the data I wanted,sometimes I got someting like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = {
                'cookie' : "fb986eadbd19c9f4bb7666aa830ca5cb",
                'uri' : "http://www.kuaishou.com/photo/403873037/3984549064?ksjs_sig=1511707099647.0",
            };

            function getCookie(c_name){
                if (document.cookie.length>0){
                    c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")
                    if (c_start!=-1){
                        c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1
                        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start)
                        if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length
                            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end))
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            function setCookie(c_name,value,expirehours){
                var exdate=new Date();
                exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours()+expirehours);
                document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expirehours==null) ? "" : "; path=/; expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
            }

            function jump(){
                setCookie('ksbv_sign_javascript', data['cookie'], 1);
                if( data['uri'].indexOf('ksjs_sig') === -1 ){
                    window.location = data.uri + ( data.uri.indexOf('?')===-1?'?':'&')  + 'ksjs_sig=' + (+ new Date);
                }else{
                    window.location = data.uri;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="javascript:jump()">
    </body>
</html>
```

I have not idea what's going on.Why did the same request get different response?And what's the purpose of this piece of javascript?

Comment: It looks like this script is used to redirects to another URL. It also ensures that the URL will only work for sometime hours in your case) and then change (a technique used in a lot of video streaming websites).

Comment: The url of the web page hosting the video resource never changes.I still cant understand...

Comment: It doesn't change for hours, then it redirects very quickly that you don't notice it happening.

Comment: thanks a lot.Could you give me any advice on  crawling this content?

Comment: Sorry if you read my just-deleted comment. I made a mistake, I gues what you should do is check if the url has a parameter `ksjs_sig`, if so then update its value to the current time (in milliseconds), if not then add the parameter `ksjs_sig` using the same current time value. Then use the new url to send the request. I'm not sure though as I don't know exactly how to solve this problem but give my suggestion a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot.You were right,I got that content.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked.